# httpsys module in production

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs application that needs to run in Windows using the certificates from the windows store. For this I found a module called httpsys which I am able to bind a particular port to a certificate.
So I wanted to know if this module is already in use in prod and if there are any issues using it.

Answer (score 0):

The module author says

> This is a very early version of the module. Not much testing or performance optimization had been done.

I guess there is not too much experience yet, but why not try it yourself and give some feedback to the developer?